# Swift generics: "Generic parameter T could not be inferred"

Tags: swift, generics, moya

I'm trying to make a generic request handler class based on Moya and Object Mapper.
Basically I want a method that performs a request to a Moya Target and performs some basic handling on both sucess and failure cases:

my class would be something like this based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061033/generic-parameter-t-could-not-be-inferred-factory-methods):

```
class APIRequestHandler<T: Mappable> {
  let provider = APIManager().getAPIProvider() // Moya provider

  func performRequest(target: Target, completionHandler: (response: T?, error: StoreError?) -> Void) {
    provider.request(target) { result in
      switch result {
      case let .Success(response):
        switch response.statusCode {
        case 200..<300:
          do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response.data, options: .MutableContainers)
            let contractualDocument = Mapper<T>().map(json)
            completionHandler(response: contractualDocument!, error: nil)
          } catch _ {
            // Unexpected error when the response can't be parsed
            completionHandler(response: nil, error: StoreError.UnexpectedError)
          }
        case 500:
          completionHandler(response: nil, error: StoreError.ServerError)
        default:
          completionHandler(response: nil, error: StoreError.HTTPError(statusCode: response.statusCode))
        }
      case .Failure(_):
        completionHandler(response: nil, error: StoreError.NetworkError)
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

My question is if I can get the same results using generics at a function level instead of class level:

```
  func performRequest<T: Mappable>(target: Target, completionHandler: (response: T?, error: StoreError?) -> Void) {
    provider.request(target) { result in
      switch result {
      case let .Success(response):
          // blah, blah
      case .Failure(_):
          // bleh, bleh
      }
    }
  }
```

I've tried it and I get a build error on my code:

`Generic parameter "T" could not be inferred`

Comment: How are you calling the method?

Comment: `performRequest(<someTarget>) { response, error in 
        // handle result
    }
`
I think my question should be: "How can I specify the type of `response`" at that level?

Comment: `performRequest(<someTarget>) {(response:<some optional response type>, error:StoreError?) in ...}` – If you edit your post to reflect your new question, then I can add this as an answer if you want. You could also go ahead and delete it, depending if you think it would be of use to anyone else.